# Multiple layouts in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

In my site I want two layouts.

1. Main layout comes when no login.
2. Whenever a user logs in there will be 1 more layout inside 1st with menu for account changes etc.

Can anyone explain how can we do it.?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the navigation for logged in/not logged in users,  look into role privileges in zend_navigation_page

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.pages.html

Answer (score 0):

Several options.

One is to use a pre-dispatch front controller plugin.  Simply check Zend_Auth to see if user is logged in.  If so, then set the layout to the 'logged-in' layout, else leave as default layout.

Another option is to check Zend_Auth from inside your actual layout file, and only include the additional code/formatting if they are logged in.